# when i test api it shows method not allowed error

Tags: python, flask

i am trying to make api for prediction using deep learning model while i test the api is shows The method is not allowed for the requested URL please help me to solve problem.
please tell me whats going wrong in this code.

app.py file.

```
from flask import Flask,Response , request , flash , url_for,jsonify
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def hello():
   return "Hello World!"
@app.route('/predict',methods=['POST'])
def classify():
  app.logger.debug('Running classifier')
  upload = request.files['data']
  image = load_image(upload)
  #load_image() is to process image :
  print('image ready')
  try:
    prediction = run_model(image)
    return _json_parse({"prediction": prediction})
  except FileNotFoundError as e:
    return abort('Unable to locate image: %s.' % str(e), 503)
  except Exception as e:
    return abort('Unable to process image: %s.' % str(e), 500)



if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run()
```

help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the error? I can only assume that you're trying to access `classify()` with a GET request but your question is totally unclear. Why do you need all the imports and keras stuff if the error is just accessing a route? Please see how to make a [mcve]

Comment: i am getting following error in browser.

Comment: Method Not Allowed

The method is not allowed for the requested URL.

Answer (score 1):

Browsers only make GET requests, as far as I can see you accepting POST method on path '/predict'.

You would either need HTML form to do post in a browser, or you can use for example [Postman](https://www.postman.com/) for this.

Comment: when i use postman it show following error `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>400 Bad Request</title>
<h1>Bad Request</h1>
<p>The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.</p>`

Comment: 400 means you did something wrong when you were submitting your request through postman. I am not a python developer but it seems to me that your requesting files/image in your post request. Maybe you didn't provide them?